# Catch requests to non-existent classes (not autoload)

Tags: php, oop, class

Is there a manner in which to catch requests to a class which does not exist.

I'm looking for something exactly like __call() and __static(), but for classes as opposed to methods in a class.

I am **not** talking about autoloading. I need to be able to interrupt the request and reroute it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way of intercepting

```
$variable = new Classname();
```

without extremely resource-draining things like Reflection or parsing the script files before executing them.

As far as I can see, autoloading is the closest you'll get here.

If you *need* to do this, you may have to build a custom factory function

```
$variable = newClass("Classname", $arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

and do your intercepting there.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Yeah a factory is not quite viable in this case. It's not required to move forward, but would be a bit cleaner. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not talking about autoloading. I
>   need to be able to interrupt the
>   request and reroute it.
>
> Ideas?

I'm not convinced autoload can't do what you need. If a request comes in for an undefined class, autoload can load the appropriate class file which would contain a class that has a combination of reflection and __call/__get, etc... and be able to process the request.

Comment: +1.  You could probably even create a stub class from within autoload, provided you're not planning on actually loading the real class later.

Comment: You can also throw an Exception from autoloading function (just make sure it's tha last autoloader on the spl_autoload stack), which you can later catch and handle anyway you wish.